# Using headerPullView in appcelerator

Tags: appcelerator, page-refresh

I'm using a tableView with a headerPullView.
It works fine, but i want to show the headerPullView when i open the tab so the user can see that new data is loaded.

Can't find any information on google or appcelerator docs.

I only found this: http://developer.appcelerator.com/blog/2010/05/how-to-create-a-tweetie-like-pull-to-refresh-table.html
but this only shows how to update when the tab is already loaded. I'm looking for a way to show that loading headerPullView when i open that window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't simulate a scroll with the `headerPullView` but you can fire an event of `scroll`.

Anyways what I would advise is to create a `headerView` and set the table height smaller and away from the top. Attache a listener to the `open` event.

```
var headerView = Ti.UI.createView({
    top: 0,
    height: 60
});

Ti.UI.currentWindow.addEventListener('open', function(e) {
    tableView.top = 60;
    tableView.height = 400;
    Ti.UI.currentWindow.add(headerView);
    Ti.UI.currentWindow.add(tableView);
});
```

Then just set it all back the way you need it when you scroll the table the first time.

```
var scrolled = 0;
tableView.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
    if(!scrolled) {
        tableView.top = 0;
        tableView.height = 460;
        Ti.UI.currentWindow.remove(headerView);
        scrolled = 1;
    }
    // scroll code
});
```

I'm not so sure why you need to do this however. After facebook replaced "shake to refresh" with this method I've started seeing it in almost all table apps and have come to just expect it. I assume many other users feel the same way about this?

Comment: thanks for your anser. I'm using facebook a lot but i never used the shake to refresh gesture. I did not know it existed! But when i open a tap i want the content to be refreshed and i need some kind of activity indicator. since i have the pull to refresh it only seems logic to show the activity there.

Comment: Ah yeah sorry about that, the "shake to refresh" is way old school now, it was in the original iPhone app FB released before it even had that main dashboard. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kg5VhadzptA

Answer (score 2):

you can use listView instead of tableView, it supports pull view already

check this
http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/ListViews-section-37521650_ListViews-PulltoRefresh

or you can use this modules

https://github.com/jolicode/Alloy-PullToRefresh